# Jenkins /Unittest/Python: test run has stopped and did not complete all test.

Tags: python, jenkins, python-unittest

i want to run multiple test files. Each file has 10-15 test cases. If first file has failing test cases, test execution stops and rest of the test cases are not being executed.

my shell command from jenkins:

```
cd $WORKSPACE/RestAPI
echo "starting test..."
python first_file.py ${VERSION} ${PROJECT_ID} ${API_VERSION}
python second_file.py ${VERSION} ${PROJECT_ID} ${API_VERSION}
python third_file.py ${VERSION} ${PROJECT_ID} ${API_VERSION}
python forth_file.py ${VERSION} ${PROJECT_ID} ${API_VERSION}
python fifth_file.py ${VERSION} ${PROJECT_ID} ${API_VERSION}
```

How can i run all tests with no stopping? 
I am expecting result after test run: 50 test Pass, 20 fail (across all test files. ) 
Thank you!

Comment: are you using a python framework to run the unit tests?  some of them have options to continue on test failure.  If not, you could wrap each python command in a try catch

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, i am using Python for my test. I added try catch. It detects the failures, but Jenkins Junit report does not display it as Failed test.

Comment: I found solution. maybe someone will need: in Jenkins > configure > Build > make separate build steps for each python file and in advanced option set "Exit code to set build" == 1. And if first set fails , than Jenkins will continue running rest of the files.